# Possible causes for custom extensions working on 1.7 but not 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, extensions, migration

I have a custom magento extension installed on several 1.7 sites and 1.9 sites. functionality does not work on the 1.9 sites.

What are common reasons that an extension might work on 1.7 but not on 1.9, where can I see what are the points that are influencing these incompatibilities?

Some difference for extension compatibility difference between 1.7 and 1.9 include the requirement of a form_key for any form functionality on the frontend.

Another is that blocks might need to be added under System > Appearance to be visible on the frontend.

With patch SUPEE-6788, admin routers needed to be changed.

Comment: Did you mean the opposite? Your title and question body conflict

Comment: A little bit more info/context might help

Comment: I added some things I know need to be changed, but I'm trying to keep the question applicable to all people updating a module. How to troubleshoot and figure out why modules would work on one system and not the other.  one last week I ran into was depracated code, getCustomerGroupCode() doesn't work in 1.9.